# How to identify remove duplicates based on all columns except for one?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, filtering

I have data like the following data frame, want to find the duplicates based on all the columns except for date, use that excluded column (date) to determine which rows are to be removed (only keep the most recent date). Doing all this without losing columns.

```
   ID    Fn       Ln       date
1   1   Joe   Schmoe 2001-01-01
2   1   Joe   Schmoe 2010-01-01
3   6   Joe   Schmoe 2001-01-01
4   2 Stacy Fakename 2002-02-02
5   2 Stacy Fakename 2020-02-02
6   3 Craig  Collins 2030-03-03
7   3 Craig  Collins 2003-03-03
8   4   Leo     Fern 2040-04-04
9   4   Leo     Fern 2004-04-04
10  5 Penny  Diamond 2005-05-05
11  5 Penny  Diamond 2050-05-05
```

So the code for the three Joe Schmoe rows should find there are only two rows alike. One is disqualified because of ID being different and the remaining two are the same except for date where the 2010 one should remain.

I ultimately want to keep the uniques like Joe ID 6 and the most recent duplicate (Joe ID 1 Date 2010) in the same table, deleting the old dupe (Joe ID 1 Date 2001).

### data

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), 
                   Fn=c("Joe", "Joe", "Joe", "Stacy", "Stacy", "Craig", "Craig", "Leo", "Leo", "Penny", "Penny"), 
                   Ln=c("Schmoe", "Schmoe", "Schmoe", "Fakename", "Fakename", "Collins", "Collins", "Fern", "Fern", "Diamond", "Diamond"), 
                   date=c("2001-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-02-02", "2020-02-02", "2030-03-03", "2003-03-03", "2040-04-04", "2004-04-04", "2005-05-05", "2050-05-05")
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each ID create a vector that gives the `order` of the underlying `integer` structure of dates, which can easily be done with `ave`. To make sure you have dates, use `as.Date(date)`. Finally, simply subset for the `1`<sup>st</sup>s.

```
> subset(data, ave(-as.integer(as.Date(date)), ID, FUN=order) == 1L)
   ID    Fn       Ln       date
2   1   Joe   Schmoe 2010-01-01
3   6   Joe   Schmoe 2001-01-01
5   2 Stacy Fakename 2020-02-02
6   3 Craig  Collins 2030-03-03
8   4   Leo     Fern 2040-04-04
11  5 Penny  Diamond 2050-05-05
```

---

*Data:*

```
data <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  Fn = rep(c("Joe", "Stacy", "Craig", "Leo", "Penny"), rep(3:2, c(1L, 4L))),
  Ln = rep(c("Schmoe", "Fakename", "Collins", "Fern", "Diamond"), rep(3:2, c(1L, 4L))),
  date = c(
    "2001-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2001-01-01", "2002-02-02", "2020-02-02",
    "2030-03-03", "2003-03-03", "2040-04-04", "2004-04-04", "2005-05-05",
    "2050-05-05"
  )
)
```

Comment: So the actual data has like 18 columns that need to match. The ID alone won't do it. I need the code to read all the other columns (ID, fn, ln in this case) to define a duplicate. So if I replace ID with c(columns 1-18), would that work?

Comment: @user22757672 Have you tried the code on your real data?

Comment: yes, it seems to work, but I want to understand and make sure the code is doing what I am intending. Say there are two Joe Schmoes and the only thing different about them is their dobs, but the date they joined are different. I'm afraid if this code doesn't account for more than their ids, then a person could be deleted. Or more likely at this step,  there are multiple rows for the same person bc they have multiple contacts that theyve updated. If you check only id, then you would call them duplicates, but the rows contain email and phone and are different based on the contacts row.

Comment: @user22757672 Good. You may want to read `?ave` to understand what the function actually does, which is grouping date (the first argument) by ID (second) and returns `order` (the `FUN=` argument). `subset` on `== 1` accordingly just keeps most recent date (by ID). ID should uniquely correspond to Fn, Ln and other stuff you've mentioned.

Comment: The actual "ID" in my datset is three columns that together make each row unique. I put list(ID1, ID2, ID3) in place of ID. Its taking forever to run, though.

Comment: @user22757672 Try `subset(data, ave(-as.integer(as.Date(date)), Reduce(paste, data.frame(ID1, ID2, ID3)), FUN=order) == 1L)`. Or alternatively `by(data, ~ID1 + ID2, \(x) subset(x, as.Date(x$date) == max(as.Date(x$date)))) |> do.call(what='rbind')`, which will disrupt the order and is slower, though, but you can re-`order` afterwards.

Comment: The first one worked like a charm, thanks for the help